# Жених и невеста

Tags: этимология

"Жених" — понятно, тот, кто женится, а "невеста"? От какого слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попрошу обратить внимание, что существует очень созвучное слово - **НЕВЕСТКА**. Касательно **НЕВЕСТЫ** словарь Фалмера приводит такое толкование:

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. нєвѣста (νύμφη; Супр.), русск. невеста, неве́стка, укр. невíста, белор. неве́ста, болг. невя́ста «невеста, молодая женщина», сербохорв. нѐвjеста «невеста, невестка», словенск. nevẹ́sta — то же, чешск. nevěsta — тоже, словацк. nevesta, польск. niewiasta «женщина», в.-луж. ńewěsta. Лучшей по-прежнему остается стар. этимология, которая видит здесь первонач. знач. «неизвестная» (см. не и ве́дать), ср. в.-луж. wěstу «известный, определенный», ńewěsty «неизвестный». Ср. алб. rē «невестка», букв. «новая». Табуистическое название должно было защитить женщину, вступающую в чужой для нее дом, дом ее жениха, от злых духов; этим же объясняется и наличие у нее свадебного покрывала. Ср. еще русск. диал. чужо́й, чуже́нин «жених», арханг. (Подв.), в.-луж. přikhodna dźowka «сноха». Все прочие этимологии сомнительны; из соединения nе и vedǫ; ср. лит. nevẽdęs «неженатый»; не более удачно возведение к *nevověsta. От но́вый и веду́ (др.-русск. веду, вести «жениться»), потому что остается необъясненным ě. Неубедительны попытки толковать *věstа как прич. прош. страд. от *vedǫ, поскольку подобные формы не засвидетельствованы. Точно так же неубедительно произведение из и.-е. превосходной степ. (ср. др.-инд. náviṣṭhas «самый молодой»), т. е. первонач. *nevьsta, сближенное потом с věděti; невероятно и *nevě(i)sta. Сомнительно объяснение из *nevě- «ново-» и *sthā-, т. е. «в новом состоянии», а также из *nevěvьsta от чешск. vdáti sе «выйти замуж», ср. др.-инд. víndatē, vindáti «достигает», vittás, из *nev-ēdtā, якобы прич. прош. страд. от *ēdō «беру себе», ср. др.-инд. ādаs «принимающий», āt-tas «принятый». Следует также отклонить сравнение с лит. nuo- и vaĩzdas «помолвка» или с не и лит. vaisà «плодородие», pavaĩsti «зачать», т. е. «не зачавшая». Наконец, неприемлемо предположение о родстве с лат. noverca «мачеха» с исходным *nevēsōr.

Comment: Я вообще не различаю этимологию невесты и невестки. Очевидно, что она общая.  
Но все, что сказано, что можно найти у Фасмера и в другтх источниках - не более чем предположения, двлеко не всеми принимаемые. Более тог, Фасмер прямо говорит о тос, что табуистическая этимология - наиболее вероятна.

Comment: > Очевидно, что она общая

Значит не только я так думаю =)

Answer (score 0):

Слово праславянское, достоверной этимологии нет.

Возможна табуистическая "охранная" этимология от "не весть" - "неизвестно кто". Тем самым якобы избегалось использование семантики "чужой", "неродной".

Answer (score 0):

В испанском "невеста" - novia, "жених" - novio.
Созвучно со словом "новый" (nuevo).

Answer (score 0):

Из всего можно сделать вывод, что род мог иметь два определения: происхождение(для чего) и принадлежность(от чего).

Происхождение было связано с женским, а долженствование с мужским.

Невеста - неизвестная, неизвестного происхождения, то что она порождает, неизвестно для чего, а жена - рожающая, та кто может быть матерью в роду, дающая материальное начало роду вписанная в систему родовых отношений.

Жених - их жён, принадлежащий по происхождению. Чужой? ну не может и так, хотя скорее не наш, а их.

Жених берет невесту в жены - делает женой своего рода.

Сноха - относящаяся, но не к ним, а к их роду.

Зять - тот, кто взял, ранее принадлежащее.

Све+кровь и свё+кор? Кор(корень? основа)-кровь, сведение основ?

Тесть, теща от тесать? в смысле те, кто выстругал ребенка, заготовочку для взрослого ~ настрогать детей. Дерево это род.